# How to dynamically center align text in a char * string to fit in a total of 16 spaces in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory

I am trying to center align strings in a total of 16 spaces to eventually print them on a 16x2 LCD Display. The values are grabbed from a database, and put in a global variable that is constantly being updated.

The values in the database are already in string format.

What I'd like to do is after getting the value from the DB, update the global variable to contain a string centered in 16 spaces.

I understand using global variables may not be best practice but ignoring that is there a way to do this?

```
char * systemInfoValues[5] = {" "," "," "," "," "}
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){
     systemInfoValues[i] = PQgetvalue(res,i,0); //get the value from db;
     int len = strlen(systemInfoValues[i]);
     char tmp[20];

     sprintf(tmp,"%*s", (17-len)/2 + len, systemInfoValues[i]);
     strcpy(systemInfoValues[i],tmp);
}
```

0 = a blank space
xxxxx = string from db

If the length of the string is odd 
I expect the output to be [00xxxxxxxxxxxxx0]

if the length of the string is even
I expect the output to be [00xxxxxxxxxxxx00]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple 6 line function. symetry is giving you the option

```
char *centerinstring(char *buff, size_t len, const char *str, int symetry)
{
    size_t strl = strlen(str);
    size_t pos = (len - strl) / 2 + (strl & 1) * !!symetry;

    memset(buff,' ', len);
    buff[len] = 0;

    memmove(buff + pos, str, strl);
    return buff;
}

int main()
{
    char buff[11];

    printf("|%s|\n", centerinstring(buff, 10, "1234567", 1));
    printf("|%s|\n", centerinstring(buff, 10, "1234567", 0));

    return 0;
}
```

or with the option to allocate memory for the buff (if you pass NULL

```
char *centerinstring(char *buff, size_t len, const char *str, int symetry)
{
    size_t strl = strlen(str);
    size_t pos = strl / 2 + (strl & 1) * !!symetry;

    buff = buff ? malloc(len + 1) : buff;

    if(buff)
    {
        memset(buff,' ', len);
        buff[len] = 0;

        memmove(buff + pos, str, strl);
    }
return buff;
}
```

Comment: What is the symmetry option?

Comment: if not even you can have this one additional space on the right or left

Comment: Okay, buff here is the database value, and str is a temp? or other way around?

Comment: it does not matter

Comment: ```
char tmp[20];
memset(tmp, ' ',len);
tmp[len] = 0;
memmove(tmp+pos,systemInfoValues[i],strl);
strcpy(systemInfoValues[i],tmp);
``` Results in seg fault

Comment: use function as given.

Comment: Function works with "1234567" but not with my strings. Here is a description of what is returned from PQGetValue: "For data in text format, the value returned by PQgetvalue is a null-terminated character string representation of the field value."

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way (without using the sprintf function).
I don't know about any interface of the sprintf function that would allow you to do it, but you can solve the problem using simple strcpy of variables.

This is a main program that would solve your problem, it is documented in itself, so you should be able to understand how to apply this to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <string.h>                                                                                                                                                                            

/* This simple program would transfer the original string that is in the                                                                                                                       
 * out_value to be centralized in this variable. */                                                                                                                                            
int main(void) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    char out_value[17] = "1234567891";                                                                                                                                                         
    char temp[20] = {0};                                                                                                                                                                       
    int first_index = 0;                                                                                                                                                                       
    int string_length = 0;                                                                                                                                                                     

    /* Copy the string to the temp variable, to modify the chars in                                                                                                                            
     * out_value. */                                                                                                                                                                           
    strcpy(temp, out_value);                                                                                                                                                                   

    /* Find out the index for the first char to be placed in the centralized                                                                                                                   
     * string. */                                                                                                                                                                              
    string_length = strlen(temp);                                                                                                                                                              
    first_index = (16 - string_length) / 2;                                                                                                                                                    

    /* Set all the values of the out_value to be the wanted value of space (here                                                                                                               
     * it is 0 for visualizing, it can be space to not be present). */                                                                                                                         
    memset(out_value, '0', 16);                                                                                                                                                                

    /* Copy the original string back, moving the start of it, so it would be                                                                                                                   
     * centralized. */                                                                                                                                                                         
    strncpy(&(out_value[first_index]), temp, string_length);                                                                                                                                   

    /* Print the string. */                                                                                                                                                                    
    printf("%s", out_value);                                                                                                                                                                   
}
```

When modifying your code to work with this, the code would look something like this:

```c
char * systemInfoValues[5] = {NULL}                                                                                                                                                            
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){                                                                                                                                                                       
     systemInfoValues[i] = PQgetvalue(res,i,0); //get the value from db;                                                                                                                       
     int len = strlen(systemInfoValues[i]);                                                                                                                                                    
     char tmp[20];                                                                                                                                                                             
     int first_index = 0;                                                                                                                                                                      

     strcpy(tmp, systemInfoValues[i]);                                                                                                                                                         
     first_index = (16 - len) / 2;                                                                                                                                                             

     memset(systemInfoValues[i], ' ', 16);                                                                                                                                                               
     strncpy(&(systemInfoValues[i][first_index]), tmp, len);                                                                                                                                   
}
```

---

Note that I changed the initializing of the value of systemInfoValues. When you initialized it, you put empty strings there. Note that this is a bad habit. Putting empty strings there (or strings with a single space) would allocate the memory for this string (which you will never use).

You didn't include the definition to the function of PQgetvalue, but assuming that it would return a char pointer, this should work.
But, this code would change the global value as well. If you don't want to change it, you shoudn't put the result there, but copy the result to the string before doing any changes to it.
After modifying the code, it should look like this:

```c
char systemInfoValues[5][17] = {{0}}                                                                                                                                                           
for(int i=0; i< 5; i++){                                                                                                                                                                       
     char *global_reference = PQgetvalue(res,i,0); //get the value from db;                                                                                                                    
     int len = strlen(systemInfoValues[i]);                                                                                                                                                    
     char tmp[20];                                                                                                                                                                             
     int first_index = 0;                                                                                                                                                                      

     strcpy(tmp, global_reference);                                                                                                                                                            
     first_index = (16 - len) / 2;                                                                                                                                                             

     memset(systemInfoValues[i], ' ', 16);                                                                                                                                                               
     strncpy(&(systemInfoValues[i][first_index]), tmp, len);                                                                                                                                   
}
```

**edit:** apperently there is an interface for the sprintf function to work (as you originally wanted). To see it, refer to the answer of **Swordfish**

Comment: Okay, I’ll check it out once I’m back at my desk and send an update.

Comment: *I don't know about any interface of the sprintf function that would allow ...* – I do ;p

Comment: This kind of works, I'm getting some random values at the end of the strings though. Output:  0xxxxxxxxxxxxx00, 000000xxxx0000008G, 00000xxxxxx00000PG

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Are you runnig my main function or your code? It seems that something is running over the NULL terminator at the end (it would happen if the length you gave the string is 16 and not 17, for example).

Comment: Let me try again with 17

Comment: 17 makes it worse, index 1 overwrites index 3,4,5 and adds random characters

Comment: My code, it seems as if the strings coming from PQGetValue are not acting as regular strings. Here is a description of what PQGetvalue returns: "For data in text format, the value returned by PQgetvalue is a null-terminated character string representation of the field value."

Comment: I think you should change your code to work as my last example, since it seems to be a problem connected to the return value of PQGetValue and not the centralazing code. If you can reproduce the problem in the main function, that it is connected to the centralization code, but if not, it is a problem more connected to the intreface you are using (and PQGetValue) function, and I currently don't have enough data (from your question) to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()`-comfort:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void center(char *dst, char *src, size_t width)
{
    assert(dst && src && width);

    size_t src_len = strlen(src);

    if (src_len >= width) {
        *dst = '\0';
        return;
    }

    int right = (int)(width - src_len) / 2;
    int left = right + (int)src_len;
    right -= (src_len & 1);

    sprintf(dst, "%*s%*s", left, src, right, "");
}

int main(void)
{
    char destination[17];

    center(destination, "12345678901234", sizeof(destination));
    printf("\"%s\"\n", destination);
}
```

Comment: Where can I find assert.h?

Comment: @mmajdalani It should be part of your compilers standard library?

Comment: @mmajdalani if not you can remove the `assert()` from the function. Just make sure you don't pass it NULL pointer.